# Try and Except on RuntimeError in Python not catching the Error

Tags: python, error-handling, runtime-error, try-catch, try-except

I have a recursion function which gives this error "RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in cmp" when I use a number beyond a limit. I am looking to make the except block return -1 (which is the requirement) and The control is not being transferred to the except block. Please do let me know as to what is wrong my program. Thanks in advance

```
def g(n):
        try:
        def f(x):
            if x == 1:
                return 1
            elif x == 0.5:
                return math.sqrt(PI)
            else:
                final_value = (x-1)*f(x-1)
                return final_value
    except RuntimeError:
        return -1            

    n = f(n/2.0)
    return n
```

Comment: I'm not sure what this is supposed to do. For even integers, it's just `(n/2)!`. For odd integers, it's some kind of partial extension of the factorial function into the reals—close to `gamma(n/2)`, when you'd expect `gamma(n/2 + 1)`. And for everything else (unless a rounding error happens to make you hit `1` or `0.5` on the way down), it's an infinite recursion down to negative infinity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing inside your `try` (ignoring the `IndentationError`, which hopefully isn't there in your real code) is a `def` statement. Defining the function doesn't raise a `RuntimeError`, so there's nothing to catch.

*Calling* the function raises a `RuntimeError`, so you need the `try` around a *call* to the function. The two obvious places are the recursive call:

```
try:
    final_value = (x-1)*f(x-1)
except RuntimeError:
    return -1
return final_value
```

… or around the outer call:

```
try:
    n = f(n/2.0)
except RuntimeError:
    return -1
return n
```

I don't know which one you want. Handling it in the outer call means all 1000 recursive frames get thrown away and you just `return -1` from the top level. Handling it in the inner call means you return `-1` from the innermost frame, but then each frame from there to the top multiplies the `-1` by its local `x-1` before passing it back up. Hopefully *you* know which one of those you want.